# Optimal way for stacking asynchronous callback events in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-webkit, asynccallback

I'm writing a local music streaming app using Node and NodeWebkit. In my app I scan the music folder for any directories, load the album art, and then display the art in html. However, the logic to detect the end of `.forEach()` iterators at the end of each asynchronous callback does not make clean code from a developers point of view. Logically it works but if I were to untangle this string of dependencies I'd have to rewrite all of it.

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
// Fetch the music albums

fs.readdir("./music", function(err, files) {

   if (err) {
       //return console.error(err);
   }

     //document.write(JSON.stringify(files));

 // Look specifically for music album folders (directories)
 filterDirectories("./music", files, function(dirs){

         dirs.forEach(function(dir, index, array){

            fs.readFile('./music/' + dir + "/album.json", 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);

                  if (err) {
                    return console.error(err);
                  }

                // Create a li item for every album, and append it to the unordered list

                    var li = $('<li><img /><a target="_blank"></a></li>');

                    li.find('a')
                        .attr('href', '#')
                        .text(data.album_name);

                    li.find('img').attr('src', './music/' + dir + '/' + data.album_art_loc).css('width:512px;height:512px;');

                    lis.push(li);

                     // Is this the last album folder?
                    if(index == array.length-1) {
                        // Go through the array
                        lis.forEach(function(item, index, array){
                            // add to the ul element
                            item.appendTo(ul);

                            // Have we added the last one to the ul element?
                            if(index == array.length - 1){
                                // Ok, now we initialize the flipster plugin to make it look 3D and advanced
                                $('.flipster').flipster({
                                    style: 'carousel'
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Where is `lis` initialised? How is `if(index == array.length-1) {` supposed to work?

Comment: I recommend to have a look at promises.

Comment: You also are mixing browser code with Node.js code.

Comment: @djfdev NWjs 
@Bergi lis is initialized further top the app. `lis = [];`. When the index counter has reached the last element in the list we know we have fetched all the info partaining to that album. However I have found this isn't always true as it is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

note 1, Array.forEach is synchronous. So to initialize flipster, you don t need to check the end of the **last** loop. You can just put it right after the loop.

note 2, to read each album.json file, you have right about the method. Although, you may want to use an helper such [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). Which typically exists to deal with that sort of situations.

Please check the code, i rewrote it using async. I don t guarantee it is bug free, but the final code should be very similar.

note 3, the initial fs.readdir and the call for filterDirectories seems mergeable into one async function.

note 4, it may worth to read [this](http://callbackhell.com/)

code rewrite

```
var async = require('async')

var musicFiles;
var musicDirs;
var lis = [];

async.series([
  function (next) {
    fs.readdir("./music", function(err, files) {
      if (err) next(err);
      musicFiles = files;
      next();
    });
  },
  function (next) {
   filterDirectories("./music", files, function(dirs){
     musicDirs = dirs;
     next();
   });
  },
  function (next) {
    var todos = [];
    musicDirs.forEach(function(dir){
      todos.push(function (nextTodo) {
        fs.readFile('./music/' + dir + "/album.json", 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
          if (err) nextTodo(err);
          lis.push(createLi(JSON.parse(data)));
          nextTodo();
        });
      })
    });
    async.parallelLimit(todos, 4, next);
  },
  function (next) {
    lis.forEach(function(li){
      li.appendTo(ul);
    });
    $('.flipster').flipster({
      style: 'carousel'
    });
  }
], function () {
  console.log("All done !")
})

function createLi (data) {
  var li = $('<li><img /><a target="_blank"></a></li>');
  li.find('a')
      .attr('href', '#')
      .text(data.album_name);
  li.find('img').attr('src', './music/' + dir + '/' + data.album_art_loc).css('width:512px;height:512px;');
  return li
}
```

hth.

Comment: This was the answer. I was able to make minor adjustments to this solution and my code worked exactly as it did before and now it is structured and readable.